# Tangents to a circle: $||\bf w-u||$ = $||\bf w-v||$

Tags: geometry

Points $A$ and $C$ with position vectors $\bf u$ and $\bf v$ lie on a circle center $\bf 0$ and radius $r$. Tangents to the circle at $A$ and $C$ meet at the point $B$ with position vector $\bf w$.

Show that $||\bf w-u||$ = $||\bf w-v||$. Here I have tried to use the fact that $\triangle OAB$ and $\triangle OBC$ are congruent as they share side $OB$, $\bf |u|$ and $\bf |v|$ are both $r$ and $\angle OAB$ = $\angle OCB$ (both right angles). Then I have said that $||\bf w-u||$ = $AB$ = $BC$ = $||\bf w-v||$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left\|w-u\right\|^2=\left\|w\right\|^2+\left\|u\right\|^2-2 w\cdot u=\left\|w\right\|^2+r^2-2r^2=\left\|w\right\|^2-r^2$$

and now check this is the same as $\;\left\|w-v\right\|^2\;$ . You can use the same notation I used in your last question.